# How to write this SQL against Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 5 tables:

```
TABLE_A:
    A_ID

TABLE_B:
    A_ID
    B_ID
TABLE_C:
    B_ID
    C_ID
    C_SOME_NUMBER

TABLE_D:
    A_ID
    D_ID
TABLE_E:
    D_ID
    E_ID
    E_SOME_NUMBER
```

As you can see, the mapping relationships are:

```
1 A --> n B
1 B --> n C
1 A --> n D
1 D --> n E
```

I want to write a SQL to calculate: the count of A_ID that:

```
sum(C_SOME_NUMBER) != sum(E_SOME_NUMBER)
```

But I don't know how to write this sql. My DB is Oracle

Comment: @Fluffeh's solution compares only sums that match the same `A_ID`. If `TABLE_C` matched a certain `A_ID` and `TABLE_E` didn't, would you need that `A_ID` to be counted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
    count(Q1.ID) as 'whoopsie'
from
    (
        select
            a.ID,
            sum(c.some_number) as someNum
        from
            TA a,
            TB b,
            TC c
        where
            a.ID=b.IB
            and b.ID=c.ID
        group by
            a.ID
    ) Q1,
    (
        select
            a.ID,
            sum(e.some_number) as someNum
        from
            TA a,
            TD d,
            TE e
        where
            a.ID=d.IB
            and d.ID=e.ID
        group by
            a.ID
    ) Q2
where
    Q1.ID=Q2.ID
    and Q1.someNum != Q2.someNum
```